# Sign into a webpage using default browser c#

Tags: c#, browser, authentication

I am trying to create a program that can login to a website through C#, but also using the default browser.

Currently, it works with the in-form browser fine, but I can't find the code to adapt it to work in an actual browser.

Any feedback is appreciated,

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PortalLogin2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        bool mHooked;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string input = "https://en-gb.facebook.com/";
            Process.Start(input);
        }
        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mHooked) return;

            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;

            HtmlElement username = doc.GetElementById("email");
            HtmlElement password = doc.GetElementById("pass");
            HtmlElement submit = doc.GetElementById("u_0_");

            string txtUser = "insert username here";
            string txtPass = "insert password here";
            doc.GetElementById("email").InnerText = txtUser.ToString();
            doc.GetElementById("pass").InnerText = txtPass.ToString();

            submit.InvokeMember("click");
            mHooked = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [www.seleniumhq.org](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is
>   entirely up to you. Primarily, it is for automating web applications
>   for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.
>   Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) also be
>   automated as well.

It has support for C# and other languages.

Comment: The code will likely be rolled out to a lot of people, so I'd need to adapt this code until it works. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to automate Internet Explorer by adding the COM references "Microsoft Internet Controls" and "Microsoft HTML Object Library".

Here is a working example to fill the field "email" on Facebook:

```
var ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
ie.Visible = true;

// once the page is loaded
ie.DocumentComplete += (object pDisp, ref object URL) => {
    // get the document
    mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)(object)ie.Document;

    // set the email field
    mshtml.IHTMLElement email = doc.getElementById("email");
    email.setAttribute("value", "na@na.na");
};

// naviagte to the page
ie.Navigate("https://en-gb.facebook.com/");

// wait indefinitely without blocking the current thread
new AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
```